# How do I create an extension that reads current html from android chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension, remote-debugging

I want to use [remote-debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) to create an extension or client software to load the source-code of the page displayed in the android chrome browser on the device.

how would i go about accessing this information? where are the relevant docs/api's? i have found [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) but there is only a few methods and none seem to fit my goal. I have also looked into other [sources](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol) and [link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugging-clients) but they seem to be focused on the conventional development tools.

Links

1. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging
2. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger
3. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol
4. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugging-clients

edit: How do I create an extension that reads current html from android chrome?

Comment: Unclear what exactly you are asking. Do you simply want to have an equivalent of Dev Tools for a page open on your phone? Or do you want to go deeper with debugger protocol?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: that link instructs you on how to use dev tools on your computer connecting to the chrome app on a device. I want to use this to load the html currently being looked at, and save that on my database. the issue is with how to go about utilizing it, there are mentions of a extension api, but only a few methods on there.

there are a couple of links in the question but they dont seem to stand out. will edit now

Comment: I started writing an answer, but I realized it just links to exactly the same pages in that exact order along with some commentary. That's why questions seeking off-site resources / tutorials are considered off-topic on SO. You should reformulate this question with a concrete problem in mind and a question "how to do that with debugging protocol" instead of "where can I find documentation"

Comment: I have updated the question, i preferred to ask about an API than ask a question having none of the work done myself already, being that i cant find where to start.

Comment: What you need to read is the current debugging protocol docs: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/index Extension API is low-level and relies on you crafting the protocol messages by hand.

Comment: I have asked a new question related to this. please have a look if you get the chance.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024792/how-to-attach-debugger-to-device-chrome-extention

Comment: @Xan do you want to create an answer saying what you have said in the comment, and i shall mark it correct as it should work.