# how to attach debugger to device? chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

This is the code from my chrome extension, as far as i am aware it should return all targets that i can attach a debugger to:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

console.log('launching extention');

    chrome.debugger.getTargets(function(result){

        console.log('Result!');
        console.log("count: "+result.length);
for (index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
        console.log(index+": "+result[index].url);

}

    });
});
```

This is my console output from the above extension:

[image]

This shows only tabs open in the chrome browser returned as debuggable targets.

I have my device connected and setup correctly so i can debug android chrome tabs.

[image]

Is the method i am using to try to attach to the devices debugger correct?

Related Docs Links;
[remote-debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging), [debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger), [debugger-protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol), [debugging-clients](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugging-clients).

Comment: Whoops. Seems like this API does not allow to attach to device pages. Worse, I can't find any feature requests to enable it to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops. Seems like this API does not allow to attach to device pages. Worse, I can't find any feature requests to enable it to do so.

Therefore, you will need to go low-level, and use the ["legacy workflow"](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging-legacy) to expose the debugger for raw access on the phone you're connecting.

Essentially, the important part is running ADB command

```
adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
```

that exposes the debugging interface of Android Chrome at `localhost:9222`, after which you can [use XHR / WebSockets](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#remote) to relay [raw protocol messages](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/index).

I'm afraid that's the only way; if you need the ADB step to be done automatically, you can use a [Native Host script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). Note that you still can't bypass the "pairing" part that needs to be done on the phone.

Comment: Note: this really needs a feature request at https://crbug.com to expose device targets to the `chrome.debugger` API. If OP could create one and state his use case, it would be great.

Comment: Also, please note: this is my **best (informed) guess**, not an authoritative answer.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=450012&thanks=450012&ts=1421676995

have i filed a request correctly? haven't needed to do this before.

Comment: Since your request was _already_ processed by a Chrome team member _(I'm honestly jealous)_, it is okay.

Comment: Hm, no, you indicated this worked before - when it didn't. I'll post a comment on the bug,

Comment: that was one part i was unsure about :P and i think indicating that would be why it got looked into so fast XD...